# R Shiny - Resetting a group of dynamically created inputs using shinyjs::reset

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

The app below has two buttons: `Add` and `Reset All`. Clicking `Add` inserts a UI object that contains:

1. Two inputs, `Month` and `Year`.
2. A remove button, `Remove`, that deletes the object when clicked.

Clicking `Reset All` resets all inserted inputs to their original values.

Here is a screenshot of the app after `Add` was clicked three times:

[image]

The app is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),

  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.shiny-split-layout > div { overflow: visible; }'))),

  tagList(
    span(
      actionButton('add', 'Add'),
      actionButton('reset', 'Reset All')
    ),
    fluidRow(div(id = 'placeholder'))
  )

)

# SERVER
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rv = reactiveValues(ctn = 0)

  observeEvent(input$add, {

    rv$ctn = rv$ctn + 1

    Id = function(id) paste0(id, rv$ctn)

    insertUI(
      selector = '#placeholder',
      ui = div(
        id = Id('inputGroup'),
        splitLayout(
          cellWidths = '10%',
          h4(Id('Month ')),
          selectInput(Id('month'), 'Month:', month.name),
          selectInput(Id('year'), 'Year:', 1510:1550),
          actionButton(Id('remove'), 'Remove'))
      )
    )

    remove_id = Id('remove')
    remove_group = Id('inputGroup')

    observeEvent(input[[remove_id]], {

      removeUI(selector = paste0('#', remove_group))

    })
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {

    reset('placeholder')
  })
}

# Run app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The `Reset All` button seems to be working for the most part but fails in the following case:

1. Click `Add`.
2. Make changes to the inputs for Month 1 and hit `Reset All` - works here, inputs for Month 1 are reset to their initial values.
3. Click `Add` again.
4. Change the `Year` for Month 2 and click `Reset All` - not working here, the `Year` input for Month 2 is **not** reset to its initial value (*however, clicking `Reset All` again does reset the value, which is confusing*).

I'm not sure what's causing this behaviour or how to remedy it so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what is causing the issue, but for a simple workaround call `reset('placeholder')` twice in your reset-observer.